# Django Multiple primary key and DB normalization

Tags: django, database-normalization

I´m currently working on my Django project and I´m facing some trouble trying to make the models and to mantain them normalized using my logical sctructure as template.

My app needs data divided into 13 columns. The rows are the columns they depend on (unreal column names):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |   I   |   J   |   K   | L | M |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+---+---+
| - | - | - | B | A | A | B | B | CONST | CONST | CONST | C | C |
| - | - | - | C | B | B | C | C | -     | -     | -     | D | D |
| - | - | - | - | C | C | - | - | -     | -     | -     | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+---+---+
```

A, D , E , F , G and H are the only columns which will have "real" data. The rest are there just for the relations but once created they are constants. The constant named column do not depend on anything, they are the same for every case.

Applying normalization I got:

Table I

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| B | C | D | G | H | 
+---+---+---+---+---+
| x | x | - | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Table II

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | E | F | 
+---+---+---+---+---+
| x | x | x | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Table III

```
+---+---+---+---+
| C | D | L | M |
+---+---+---+---+
| x | x | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+
```

The problems I see are that I don´t know how to have multiple primary key which a part of them work as primary key in other tables.Should I creat some type of intermediate model?

Regarding the constants I thought about maken a constant class model without using the DB so I can use their values as other models w/o needing to make querys and with no extra code.

```
class Constants(models.Model):
    I = VALUE
    J = VALUE
    K = VALUE
```

What do you think?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when some design seems hard to implement in Django, you have 3 choices: ditch Django, choose a more idiomatic route or... suffer. Django is very opinionated as a framework, and it has no support for composite primary keys (unique_togheter may help in some cases). You may replace the ORM with SQLAlchemy but then it is probably better to use Flask instead of Django.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately I muss use Django so I would try the "more idiomatic" option. I´m gonna go and try surrogative keys and middle models and see which of them work better.